Find empty directories and subdirectories from a root path
Given a path, provide a list of all empty directories and subdirectories.
I found many answers for listing only directories(subdirectories) or only files under a given path.
I need a list of all directories and subdirectories that are empty in order to delete them.

You don't need the list to delete the empty directories - you can zap them as you are recursing the tree.  If you try that, make a backup first:)

This is the best I could achieve on my own:
import os
def findEmptyDir(path, empty_dir_array):
    for sdir in os.scandir(path):
        if sdir.is_dir():
            files = [f for f in os.scandir(sdir.path) if f.is_file()]
            if len(files) == 0:
                empty_dir_array.append({"dirpath" : sdir.path})
            findEmptyDir(sdir.path, empty_dir_array)
    return empty_dir_array


empty_dir_array = []
empty_dir_array = findEmptyDir("C:\\test", empty_dir_array)
print("Empty Dir List:", empty_dir_array)

